# Mysql query dependant on another query vs. join

Tags: php, mysql, join, while-loop

Stuck!  So I've been researching how to run a query based on the result of another query and understand that it's not efficient (and I don't get the result I'd expect.)

Here's the info I have:

I have a $_Get variable for the team_id.

I have two tables.  Table 1 and Table 2.  Table 1 has team_id and player_id while Table 2 has all the player info.

I want to get the player_name in Table2. Look at what I had in mind below to get a better id:

```
//assign and clean up tid
$tid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['tid']);

//query to find player id where the team id matches tid
$sql = "SELECT player_id FROM table1 WHERE team_id = '$tid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

//then I was basically going to run a while loop with another query to get the playerid
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$playerid=$row['player_id'];

$sql2 = "select player_name from table2 where player_id = '$playerid'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
echo $result2;
}
```

While researching this I've found that there seems to be a concensus that using mysql joins is the best way to achieve this without a while loop.  I've played around with that option but don't really understand how joins work.
How would I create a query that achieves the result I'd like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Venn visualizations help a lot: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Edit: I think this is what you're going for...

```
SELECT p.player_name
FROM players AS p
INNER JOIN team_players AS t ON (t.player_id = p.player_id)
WHERE t.team_id = $tid
```

I highly recommend picking up a SQL book.  One that's written in very accessible language is [Head First SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526849).

Comment: I'd seen that and find it very helpful.  Where I get lost is I how to I make sure only those values that match the specific team id are returned.  i.e.:  i only want the player name where the team ids are both = to a specific value.  So if the team_id is = to 7 then I only want the players in table 2 that are have the team_id of 7.

Comment: GOT IT!!! Guess thinking for a second helps lol  Here's my code: `$sql= "SELECT * FROM PLAYERS INNER JOIN TEAM_PLAYERS
ON TEAM_PLAYERS.PLAYER_ID = PLAYERS.PLAYER_ID";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 if ($row['TEAM_ID'] == $tid){
  echo $row['PLAYER_NAME'];
 }
}`

Comment: That's one way to skin it, but to get this as pure SQL check out my edit.

Comment: check out Understanding SQL Joins here:  http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Understanding-SQL-Joins/

Comment: Thanks all!  Will definitely check out the book store!